# text file processing with python

Tags: python

i have some text file which contain proxy ip .

which look like following

```
    130.14.29.111:80                          
    130.14.29.120:80                          
    130.159.235.31:80                         
    14.198.198.220:8909                       
    141.105.26.183:8000                       
    160.79.35.27:80                           
    164.77.196.75:80                          
    164.77.196.78:45430                       
    164.77.196.78:80                          
    173.10.134.173:8081                       
    174.132.145.80:80                         
    174.137.152.60:8080                       
    174.137.184.37:8080                       
    174.142.125.161:80
```

after processing check this proxy , then i want to marked as following

```
     total number of '0' = 8
     total number of 'x' = 6
     percentage = alive 60% , dead 40%


     x  130.14.29.111:80              
     0  130.14.29.120:80              
     0  130.159.235.31:80             
     0  14.198.198.220:8909           
     0  141.105.26.183:8000           
     0  160.79.35.27:80               
     x  164.77.196.75:80              
     x  164.77.196.78:45430           
     x  164.77.196.78:80              
     0  173.10.134.173:8081           
     0  174.132.145.80:80             
     0  174.137.152.60:8080           
     x  174.137.184.37:8080           
     x  174.142.125.161:80
```

how can be done with python? or some sample 
if anyone would help me or enlight me much aprreciate!

i was edited

this is script source of what i have

finally check finished proxy list are saved to 'proxy_alive.txt'

in this file i want to mark whether proxy element alive or not.

```
    import socket
    import urllib2
    import threading
    import sys
    import Queue
    import socket

    socket.setdefaulttimeout(7)

    print "Bobng's proxy checker. Using %s second timeout"%(socket.getdefaulttimeout())

    #input_file = sys.argv[1]
    #proxy_type = sys.argv[2] #options: http,s4,s5
    #output_file = sys.argv[3]
    input_file = 'proxylist.txt'
    proxy_type = 'http'
    output_file = 'proxy_alive.txt'

    url = "www.seemyip.com" # Don't put http:// in here, or any /'s

    check_queue = Queue.Queue()
    output_queue = Queue.Queue()
    threads = 20

    def writer(f,rq):
        while True:
            line = rq.get()
            f.write(line+'\n')

    def checker(q,oq):
        while True:
            proxy_info = q.get() #ip:port
            if proxy_info == None:
                print "Finished"
            #quit()
                return
            #print "Checking %s"%proxy_info
            if proxy_type == 'http':
                try:

            listhandle = open("proxylist.txt").read().split('\n')

            for line in listhandle:   
                saveAlive = open("proxy_alive.txt", 'a')

                details = line.split(':')
                email = details[0]
                password = details[1].replace('\n', '')


                proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http':proxy_info})
                opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
                opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]
                urllib2.install_opener(opener)
                req = urllib2.Request("http://www.google.com")
                sock=urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout= 7)
                rs = sock.read(1000)
                if '<title>Google</title>' in rs:
                oq.put(proxy_info)
                print '[+] alive proxy' , proxy_info
                saveAlive.write(line)
            saveAlive.close()    
                except urllib2.HTTPError,e:
            print 'url open error? slow?'
                    pass
                except Exception,detail:
                    print '[-] bad proxy' ,proxy_info

            else:
                # gotta be socks
                try:
                    s = socks.socksocket()
                    if proxy_type == "s4":
                        t = socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4
                    else:
                        t = socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5
                    ip,port = proxy_info.split(':')
                    s.setproxy(t,ip,int(port))
                    s.connect((url,80))
                    oq.put(proxy_info)
                    print proxy_info
                except Exception,error:
                    print proxy_info

    threading.Thread(target=writer,args=(open(output_file,"wb"),output_queue)).start()
    for i in xrange(threads):
        threading.Thread(target=checker,args=(check_queue,output_queue)).start()
    for line in open(input_file).readlines():
        check_queue.put(line.strip('\n'))
    print "File reading done"
    for i in xrange(threads):
        check_queue.put(None)
    raw_input("PRESS ENTER TO QUIT")
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: How do you determine whether or not it's x or 0?

Comment: Are you having trouble with processing the text file, or with determining if a proxy is `alive`/`dead`? Also, your percentages should be 57% and 43%, not 60/40%.

Comment: Here's a good starting point: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Comment: i was attached script source..

Comment: -1: It's not clear what you've tried, and it's not clear what you want help with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a queue to queue all the list of address and their meta information.
After you are done with your operation on this ip addresses, you can write it back to the same file with 'w' mode.

```
[ ( ip-address-1,'x' ), ( ip-address-2, '0'), ...... ]
```

Comment: hi i was edited again in case can't see correctly script check here pls. i was upload to pastebin too  http://pastebin.com/x7mL46Fy

Comment: The order of execution seems to be wrong on a first look, the check_queue must be build first then the checker function has to be executed and then the output_queue has to be written back to the output file. I am uploading the order in the correct format in pastebin.http://pastebin.com/NiFJsUpH

Comment: Please follow this link to test if a port is open. Its much cleaner approach.http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/how-to-keep-checking-if-port-is-open-by-issuing-socket-connects/

Comment: thanks again but actually i want to know  how can handling formatting about text file such like ' o x o o o ' percentage and so on..